# Which PHP ORM works with Oracle and does not require PDO_OCI?

Tags: php, oracle, orm

I would like to use an ORM but unfortunately there is no stable PDO for our database (Oracle).  The PHP page states that the PDO_OCI extension is "EXPERIMENTAL" and warns against using it.

It seems that both Doctrine and Propel require PDO.  What do other Oracle/PHP shops use for ORM in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doctrine 2 supports OCI8 out of the box](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.4/namespace-Doctrine.DBAL.Driver.OCI8.html).

For Doctrine 1.2 you will have to [implement your own connection class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/connections/en#writing-custom-connections) using the [OCI8 extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) (the only one actively supported by Oracle). Chances are, you will find a custom class at GitHub or by [googling for it](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=doctrine%20oci8).

As for Propel, there is an entry in the Propel Newgroups asking for it:

- https://groups.google.com/group/propel-users/browse_thread/thread/9977c9556beaf1ac

> Unfortunately Propel requires PDO and PDOStatement as parameters
>   throughout the API, so the best choice ist to extend PropelPDO and
>   PDOStatement and reimplement the needed methods with oci8.

and

> In theory, you could use Propel 1.2.x, since this uses oci8 rather than
>   pdo_oci.

Answer (score 1):

The PDO_OCI extension is technically "EXPERIMENTAL", but b'jillions (hyperbole) of people (myself included) are using it every day on production systems without a problem. It's over 6 years old and quite stable.

Answer (score 0):

How about [OCI8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.oci8.php)?

BTW you have to distinguish between the driver that is communicating with the DBMS and an ORM that is using the driver.

Comment: We use OCI8 but it does not provide much beyond prepared statements.  We are looking for a full-fledged ORM.